# Proof for strongly convex functions

Tags: proof-explanation, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

I read this theorem in the textbook *Numerical Optimization*, but I could not figure out the proof for this theorem.

Suppose $f$ is differentiable and is strongly convex with modulus $m$ and the gradient is Lipschitz with constant $M$. Then,

$[∇f(x) − ∇f(y)] · (x − y) ≥ \frac{Mm}{M + m} ||x - y||^2 + \frac{1}{M + m} ||∇f(x) − ∇f(y)||^2$

How do I prove this theorem?

Comment: Check the proof of Theorem 2.1.12 in Introductory Lectures in Convex Minimization by Nesterov (2004).